# React Native reload from JavaScript debugger

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to reload a React native app running on a device from the JavaScript debugger console?

Not a huge deal. Just curious.

The shake/reload from the device works great, but sometimes when I have an error with the red screen, the app doesn't reload with a file change, and picking up my phone and shaking it and hitting reload is usually like a 5s process.

Is there anyway I can trigger a reload from the debugger (or my computer) on an app running on a phone that I'm debugging?

e.g. > ReactNative.reload() (I know that doesn't exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by installing [frappe](https://github.com/niftylettuce/frappe). Once frappe is up and running and the device is connected, reload could be triggered by pressing cmd+shift+R button.

Comment: Ah nice. I guess I had iOS in mind but this is definitely what I was asking for. Thanks!